# Suitable design pattern for event management

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, event-handling, epoll

We have a modular architecture, in which every module works as an event **generator** as well as event **observer**. It is possible that a module can generate multiple events at same time.

We can have two architecture for handling events:

1. Maintain an observer list for different type of events and call their handlers one by one.

   ```
   class Module{
       vector<Module*> event_observer_list[CNT_OF_EVENTS];
       int register(Module* observer, int event_type){
           event_observer_list[event_type].push_back(observer);
       }
       void generate_event(list_of_event_indices){
           for(auto event_index : list_of_event_indices){
               for(auto i : event_observer[event_index])
                   event_observer_list[event_index][i]->handler(some_params);
           }
       }
       int handler(some_params){
           ...
       }
   };
   ```

   In this case we will have to call same observer function `handler()` multiple times for multiple events. Even if we write
   separate handlers for each event, we may have to perform some common task (like getting an object from 
   a synchronized map) in each call, which makes this architecture enefficient.
2. Maintain an observer list common for all events. We will call each module's handler one by one. 
   If a module is not looking for some specific event then it will just skip the processing.

   ```
   class Module{
       vector<Module*> event_observer_list;
       int register(Module* observer){
           event_observer_list.push_back(observer);
       }
       void generate_event(list_of_event_types){
           for(i = 0 to event_observer_list.size()){
               event_observer_list[i]->handler(some_params, list_of_event_types);
           }
       }
       int handler(some_params, list_of_event_types){
           ...
       }
   };
   ```

   This architecture is also enefficient because, it is making us to call some unnecessary handlers.

Please provide any possible optimization in the existing architectures or give a totally different design solution.

### EDIT

`epoll` (I/O event notification facility) API provides similar kind of event management facility as I am looking for. It notifies multiple event simultaneously according to registration was made. I tried, but was not able to understand how do they manage it. Someone having a good understanding of `epoll` source code can help me here.

Comment: I don't see many difference between the two, you just put the responsibility of dispatch to different position. Besides that, I would say generate **list of** event is pretty strange IMHO.

Comment: @appleapple I once worked on a system that had external notifications over TCP.  We used to buffer the events a bit for more efficient transport, so a list of events was sent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is some magic solution for this.  You want to handle several events and you want them handled by several observers.

One possible optimization might be for a limited number of events, where you match bit-flags per different event with bit-flags per observer.  e.g. observer is interested in event 1,3 and 5 (bits: 0x0015).  event 1, 2 and 4 are sent (bits 0x000B), so the handler for this observer is called because 0x0015 & 0x000B is not zero (event 1 is common).

The efficiency difference of both proposed solutions depends mostly on the chance that many events are sent simultaneously.
If this is not the case most of the time, then only calling the interested observers per event is more efficient most of the time, because at least not all handlers have to check all events: per event only the interested observer is called.
Still it might be slightly less efficient under load when most events are likely to be send and you need most efficiency (this is assuming that most observers will handle at least one event).

My preference goes to the first approach because although the bookkeeping is a bit more complex, overall you can expect more efficiently, although there are cases where approach 2 might be a better fit.

Comment: I am already using bit flags for events, but didn't mentioned it for simplicity. Although thanks for mentioning it. +1 for suggestion based on chances of simultaneous event. I have made some edit in question, can you help me with that?

Comment: Sorry, about epoll, I probably used select for too long. I'll probably look into it next time I do low-level communication with multiple connections.